# CPU occupation while using python subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess

I wrote a c++ program `a.out` and tried to run the program by using `subprocess` module in python, called `run.py`. After running the script, I used `top` to check cpu usage and found that the `run.py` does not shown in the list while `a.out` is running.

What happened to `run.py`? Where is it?

Comment: I think `top` will show you the process, which would be `python`, not `run.py`.

Comment: `top` does not show `python` either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sleeping waiting for your C++ program to exit. That is because you used `subprocess.call`.

You can use `subprocess.Popen` which doesn't wait unless you call its `wait` method if you need your Python program to continue doing something else while the program runs.